# How to use a loop to work out a model through several variables in R

Tags: r

Here my data for boosting

```
 new=structure(list(B1 = c(6914L, 6914L, 6914L, 6958L, 6958L, 6958L, 
    6958L, 6914L, 6914L, 6914L, 6914L, 5672L, 6014L, 6014L, 6014L, 
    6014L, 6014L, 6958L, 6958L, 6958L, 6958L, 6958L, 6958L, 6914L, 
    6914L, 6914L, 6914L, 6092L, 6092L, 6092L, 6092L, 6092L, 6239L, 
    6239L, 6239L, 6239L, 6239L, 6239L, 6615L, 6615L, 6615L, 6615L, 
    6615L, 7038L, 7038L, 7038L, 7038L, 7038L, 7038L, 6602L, 8136L, 
    8136L, 7369L, 8136L, 8136L, 7369L, 8136L, 8136L, 8136L, 7369L, 
    7369L, 8136L, 8136L, 8136L, 8136L, 7369L, 7369L, 8136L, 8136L, 
    8136L, 8136L, 8317L, 8317L, 8317L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 
    8821L, 8317L, 8317L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 
    8317L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 
    8821L, 8821L, 8821L, 9245L), B2 = c(5560L, 5380L, 5644L, 5088L, 
    5280L, 5200L, 5472L, 5568L, 5560L, 5424L, 5404L, 4784L, 4696L, 
    4820L, 4588L, 4544L, 4452L, 4716L, 5048L, 5236L, 5416L, 5584L, 
    5824L, 5800L, 5932L, 5980L, 6112L, 4796L, 4860L, 5396L, 5900L, 
    5968L, 5968L, 5776L, 5440L, 5248L, 4884L, 4760L, 4796L, 4860L, 
    4776L, 4664L, 4716L, 4952L, 5168L, 5316L, 5548L, 5768L, 5900L, 
    5948L, 5796L, 5756L, 5912L, 5956L, 6000L, 6196L, 6044L, 6164L, 
    6268L, 6588L, 6508L, 6460L, 6608L, 6592L, 6600L, 7100L, 7016L, 
    6988L, 6952L, 6800L, 6644L, 7308L, 7340L, 7528L, 7492L, 7304L, 
    6928L, 6748L, 6764L, 7492L, 7648L, 7580L, 7416L, 7108L, 6864L, 
    7056L, 7164L, 7744L, 7720L, 7360L, 7188L, 7204L, 7280L, 7236L, 
    7520L, 7352L, 7352L, 7376L, 7320L, 7428L), B3 = c(4768L, 4840L, 
    4936L, 4320L, 4388L, 4572L, 4640L, 4704L, 4696L, 4488L, 4396L, 
    4002L, 4030L, 3960L, 3684L, 3680L, 3896L, 4212L, 4364L, 4508L, 
    4732L, 4896L, 4848L, 4872L, 4960L, 5052L, 4848L, 4308L, 4800L, 
    5216L, 5224L, 5248L, 5136L, 4720L, 4428L, 4120L, 3918L, 4052L, 
    4058L, 3806L, 3802L, 3930L, 4092L, 4324L, 4476L, 4604L, 4768L, 
    4980L, 5080L, 5288L, 4840L, 4936L, 5096L, 5040L, 5096L, 5292L, 
    5280L, 5360L, 5480L, 5584L, 5528L, 5524L, 5700L, 5736L, 5732L, 
    6136L, 5980L, 5884L, 5904L, 5820L, 5864L, 6488L, 6572L, 6476L, 
    6256L, 6024L, 5844L, 5884L, 6100L, 6684L, 6596L, 6376L, 6188L, 
    5952L, 6044L, 6212L, 6268L, 6668L, 6484L, 6336L, 6164L, 6332L, 
    6432L, 6396L, 6592L, 6548L, 6500L, 6464L, 6460L, 7008L), B4 = c(4960L, 
    4964L, 4540L, 4164L, 4412L, 4608L, 4628L, 4588L, 4416L, 4312L, 
    4372L, 3806L, 3652L, 3570L, 3480L, 3708L, 3886L, 4188L, 4284L, 
    4344L, 4704L, 4776L, 4772L, 4980L, 5000L, 4852L, 4508L, 4916L, 
    5356L, 5400L, 5268L, 5156L, 4620L, 4324L, 4016L, 3884L, 3854L, 
    3854L, 3770L, 3562L, 3708L, 3854L, 4084L, 4228L, 4440L, 4532L, 
    4784L, 5008L, 5292L, 5464L, 4868L, 4996L, 4908L, 4932L, 5060L, 
    5136L, 5280L, 5444L, 5492L, 5500L, 5560L, 5604L, 5704L, 5660L, 
    5716L, 5892L, 5844L, 5796L, 5752L, 5816L, 5892L, 6500L, 6488L, 
    6212L, 5928L, 5796L, 5876L, 6084L, 6284L, 6660L, 6424L, 6088L, 
    6004L, 6044L, 6268L, 6336L, 6664L, 6500L, 6308L, 6152L, 6288L, 
    6424L, 6376L, 6860L, 6464L, 6500L, 6508L, 6468L, 7144L, 7652L
    ), B5 = c(5554L, 5554L, 4782L, 4736L, 4736L, 5018L, 5018L, 4968L, 
    4968L, 4677L, 4677L, 3814L, 3667L, 3667L, 3594L, 3975L, 3975L, 
    4348L, 4348L, 4736L, 4736L, 5018L, 5018L, 4968L, 4968L, 4677L, 
    4677L, 4930L, 5524L, 5524L, 5229L, 5229L, 4424L, 4424L, 4113L, 
    4113L, 4069L, 4069L, 3857L, 3932L, 3932L, 4228L, 4228L, 4591L, 
    4591L, 4918L, 4918L, 5324L, 5324L, 5543L, 5327L, 5327L, 5301L, 
    5471L, 5471L, 5301L, 5471L, 5471L, 5846L, 5977L, 5977L, 5899L, 
    5899L, 6099L, 6099L, 5977L, 5977L, 5899L, 5899L, 6099L, 6099L, 
    6857L, 6517L, 6517L, 6220L, 6220L, 6418L, 6418L, 6969L, 6517L, 
    6517L, 6220L, 6220L, 6418L, 6418L, 6969L, 6969L, 6861L, 6581L, 
    6581L, 6729L, 6729L, 7265L, 7265L, 6581L, 6729L, 6729L, 7265L, 
    7265L, 8025L), B6 = c(5249L, 5249L, 4428L, 4553L, 4553L, 4832L, 
    4832L, 4741L, 4741L, 4428L, 4428L, 3736L, 3464L, 3464L, 3509L, 
    3894L, 3894L, 4270L, 4270L, 4553L, 4553L, 4832L, 4832L, 4741L, 
    4741L, 4428L, 4428L, 5030L, 5441L, 5441L, 4926L, 4926L, 4146L, 
    4146L, 3907L, 3907L, 3910L, 3910L, 3721L, 3831L, 3831L, 4201L, 
    4201L, 4509L, 4509L, 4871L, 4871L, 5235L, 5235L, 5217L, 5207L, 
    5207L, 5087L, 5290L, 5290L, 5087L, 5290L, 5290L, 5777L, 5721L, 
    5721L, 5746L, 5746L, 5982L, 5982L, 5721L, 5721L, 5746L, 5746L, 
    5982L, 5982L, 6504L, 6116L, 6116L, 5946L, 5946L, 6257L, 6257L, 
    6916L, 6116L, 6116L, 5946L, 5946L, 6257L, 6257L, 6916L, 6916L, 
    6407L, 6293L, 6293L, 6545L, 6545L, 7197L, 7197L, 6293L, 6545L, 
    6545L, 7197L, 7197L, 7998L), B7 = c(4893L, 4893L, 4138L, 4527L, 
    4527L, 4681L, 4681L, 4505L, 4505L, 4170L, 4170L, 3629L, 3388L, 
    3388L, 3545L, 3982L, 3982L, 4288L, 4288L, 4527L, 4527L, 4681L, 
    4681L, 4505L, 4505L, 4170L, 4170L, 5127L, 5268L, 5268L, 4703L, 
    4703L, 3996L, 3996L, 3775L, 3775L, 3713L, 3713L, 3594L, 3813L, 
    3813L, 4166L, 4166L, 4462L, 4462L, 4836L, 4836L, 5277L, 5277L, 
    4910L, 5235L, 5235L, 5001L, 5241L, 5241L, 5001L, 5241L, 5241L, 
    5688L, 5539L, 5539L, 5599L, 5599L, 5988L, 5988L, 5539L, 5539L, 
    5599L, 5599L, 5988L, 5988L, 6278L, 5864L, 5864L, 5931L, 5931L, 
    6177L, 6177L, 6896L, 5864L, 5864L, 5931L, 5931L, 6177L, 6177L, 
    6896L, 6896L, 6212L, 6159L, 6159L, 6382L, 6382L, 7383L, 7383L, 
    6159L, 6382L, 6382L, 7383L, 7383L, 7856L), B8 = c(4836L, 4840L, 
    5044L, 4074L, 4236L, 4404L, 4592L, 4668L, 4796L, 4628L, 4632L, 
    3914L, 3896L, 3796L, 3580L, 3598L, 3596L, 3830L, 4096L, 4320L, 
    4460L, 4648L, 4904L, 4980L, 4940L, 5148L, 5180L, 4164L, 4628L, 
    5304L, 5512L, 5592L, 5500L, 5216L, 4732L, 4380L, 4036L, 4008L, 
    3994L, 3784L, 3660L, 3650L, 3794L, 4018L, 4212L, 4296L, 4516L, 
    4648L, 4908L, 5148L, 4876L, 4828L, 4936L, 4992L, 5052L, 5236L, 
    5236L, 5336L, 5380L, 5708L, 5648L, 5624L, 5580L, 5724L, 5796L, 
    6280L, 6156L, 6012L, 5876L, 5864L, 5868L, 6488L, 6636L, 6752L, 
    6612L, 6268L, 5924L, 5968L, 6092L, 6752L, 6876L, 6764L, 6484L, 
    6176L, 6108L, 6300L, 6460L, 6924L, 6724L, 6528L, 6484L, 6352L, 
    6500L, 6600L, 6784L, 6876L, 6676L, 6616L, 6732L, 6896L), B8A = c(4679L, 
    4679L, 4098L, 4524L, 4524L, 4643L, 4643L, 4460L, 4460L, 3987L, 
    3987L, 3413L, 3294L, 3294L, 3490L, 3840L, 3840L, 4140L, 4140L, 
    4524L, 4524L, 4643L, 4643L, 4460L, 4460L, 3987L, 3987L, 5232L, 
    5152L, 5152L, 4421L, 4421L, 3863L, 3863L, 3697L, 3697L, 3561L, 
    3561L, 3558L, 3788L, 3788L, 4110L, 4110L, 4493L, 4493L, 4894L, 
    4894L, 5032L, 5032L, 4606L, 5209L, 5209L, 4889L, 5233L, 5233L, 
    4889L, 5233L, 5233L, 5787L, 5324L, 5324L, 5492L, 5492L, 6018L, 
    6018L, 5324L, 5324L, 5492L, 5492L, 6018L, 6018L, 5872L, 5544L, 
    5544L, 5876L, 5876L, 6279L, 6279L, 6963L, 5544L, 5544L, 5876L, 
    5876L, 6279L, 6279L, 6963L, 6963L, 6134L, 6187L, 6187L, 6547L, 
    6547L, 7280L, 7280L, 6187L, 6547L, 6547L, 7280L, 7280L, 7968L
    ), B9 = c(6752L, 6752L, 6752L, 7098L, 7098L, 7098L, 7098L, 6752L, 
    6752L, 6752L, 6752L, 4997L, 5626L, 5626L, 5626L, 5626L, 5626L, 
    7098L, 7098L, 7098L, 7098L, 7098L, 7098L, 6752L, 6752L, 6752L, 
    6752L, 5698L, 5698L, 5698L, 5698L, 5698L, 5408L, 5408L, 5408L, 
    5408L, 5408L, 5408L, 5685L, 5685L, 5685L, 5685L, 5685L, 6352L, 
    6352L, 6352L, 6352L, 6352L, 6352L, 5794L, 8407L, 8407L, 7048L, 
    8407L, 8407L, 7048L, 8407L, 8407L, 8407L, 7048L, 7048L, 8407L, 
    8407L, 8407L, 8407L, 7048L, 7048L, 8407L, 8407L, 8407L, 8407L, 
    8487L, 8487L, 8487L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 8487L, 
    8487L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 8487L, 9610L, 
    9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 9610L, 
    9610L, 10128L), B10 = c(4170L, 4170L, 3407L, 3301L, 3301L, 3612L, 
    3612L, 3600L, 3600L, 3352L, 3352L, 2502L, 2388L, 2388L, 2403L, 
    2659L, 2659L, 2979L, 2979L, 3301L, 3301L, 3612L, 3612L, 3600L, 
    3600L, 3352L, 3352L, 3856L, 4192L, 4192L, 3840L, 3840L, 3187L, 
    3187L, 2782L, 2782L, 2634L, 2634L, 2501L, 2562L, 2562L, 2792L, 
    2792L, 3068L, 3068L, 3405L, 3405L, 3816L, 3816L, 3858L, 3343L, 
    3343L, 3188L, 3438L, 3438L, 3188L, 3438L, 3438L, 3774L, 3543L, 
    3543L, 3653L, 3653L, 3934L, 3934L, 3543L, 3543L, 3653L, 3653L, 
    3934L, 3934L, 4224L, 3999L, 3999L, 3881L, 3881L, 4162L, 4162L, 
    4724L, 3999L, 3999L, 3881L, 3881L, 4162L, 4162L, 4724L, 4724L, 
    4293L, 4161L, 4161L, 4380L, 4380L, 5052L, 5052L, 4161L, 4380L, 
    4380L, 5052L, 5052L, 5756L), B11 = c(3124L, 3124L, 2514L, 2969L, 
    2969L, 3137L, 3137L, 2922L, 2922L, 2487L, 2487L, 1850L, 1822L, 
    1822L, 2014L, 2309L, 2309L, 2600L, 2600L, 2969L, 2969L, 3137L, 
    3137L, 2922L, 2922L, 2487L, 2487L, 3753L, 3535L, 3535L, 2823L, 
    2823L, 2296L, 2296L, 2151L, 2151L, 1974L, 1974L, 1924L, 2100L, 
    2100L, 2386L, 2386L, 2731L, 2731L, 3087L, 3087L, 3380L, 3380L, 
    3006L, 2740L, 2740L, 2443L, 2800L, 2800L, 2443L, 2800L, 2800L, 
    3228L, 2669L, 2669L, 2935L, 2935L, 3338L, 3338L, 2669L, 2669L, 
    2935L, 2935L, 3338L, 3338L, 3049L, 2893L, 2893L, 3087L, 3087L, 
    3550L, 3550L, 4235L, 2893L, 2893L, 3087L, 3087L, 3550L, 3550L, 
    4235L, 4235L, 3184L, 3242L, 3242L, 3774L, 3774L, 4487L, 4487L, 
    3242L, 3774L, 3774L, 4487L, 4487L, 5217L), B = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L), E = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), C = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L), OC = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L
    ), OLS = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L
    ))
```

Five column with depended vars (B,E,    C   ,OC ,OLS).
I must perform 5 boosting models. Simple i can do it.
Take this script, and just change target var 5 times(any dep var ~. )

```
# train GBM model
gbm.fit.final109 <- gbm(
  formula = Value ~ .,
  distribution = "gaussian",
  data = new,
  n.trees = 483,
  interaction.depth = 5,
  shrinkage = 0.1,
  n.minobsinnode = 5,
  bag.fraction = .65, 
  train.fraction = 1,
  n.cores = NULL, # will use all cores by default
  verbose = FALSE
)
```

However, is it possible to create some kind of loop that substitutes  column with depended var from the list into the script? For example`(mylistwithdepended_vars=c((B,E,C,OC,OLS)`) ,
I.E.we take each dependent variable, as soon as it works out in a loop, we substitute another from the list, until through this loop we work out all the columns .

How can i do it.
As output i just want 5 models

```
 gbm.fit.finalB
gbm.fit.finalE
gbm.fit.finalC
gbm.fit.finalOC
gbm.fit.finalOLS
```

Always appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Do you intend that the dependent variables are used as predictors/independent variables (in the four complementary models when they are not the response)? That is, do you want to fit  B ~ gbm(B1:B11 + E + C + IC + OLS) or B ~ gbm(B1:B11)?

Comment: @dipetkov, i mean B+C+OLS~B1:B11

Comment: Then I don't think that's what you are getting with the solution below because `model(y ~ ., data = my_data)` means use all column in my_data to model the response y. Verbose though it may be you might want to use `Value ~ B1 + B2 + B3 + B4 + B5 + B6 + B7 + B8 + B9 + B10 + B11`.

Comment: And you can see in plots that the responses have "relative influence" as if they were predictors. This is confusing, so check whether the fitted models are the models you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```r
library(gbm)
#> Loaded gbm 2.1.8

dependend <- c("B", "E", "C", "OC", "OLS")
mylistwithdepended_vars <- mget(dependend, envir = as.environment(new))

fun <- function(Value){
  gbm.fit.final109 <- gbm(
    formula = Value ~ .,
    distribution = "gaussian",
    data = new,
    n.trees = 483,
    interaction.depth = 5,
    shrinkage = 0.1,
    n.minobsinnode = 5,
    bag.fraction = .65, 
    train.fraction = 1,
    n.cores = NULL, # will use all cores by default
    verbose = FALSE
  )  
}


gbm_models <- Map(fun, mylistwithdepended_vars)

old_par <- par(mfrow = c(1, 5))
mapply(summary, gbm_models, main = names(gbm_models))
```

[image]

```
#>         B            E            C            OC           OLS         
#> var     character,17 character,17 character,17 character,17 character,17
#> rel.inf numeric,17   numeric,17   numeric,17   numeric,17   numeric,17
par(old_par)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution fits a mysterious set of 5 models (and not the models the OP has in mind) because it's not clear what the predictors are in the formula `Value ~ .`.

It's better to be explicit what the models, the response and the predictors are.

```r
library("gbm")
#> Loaded gbm 2.1.8
library("tidyverse")

data <- tibble(new)

# Let's define a function to fit a model ...
model_fn <- function(formula, data) {
  # Generalized Boosted Regression
  gbm(
    formula = formula,
    distribution = "gaussian",
    data = data,
    n.trees = 483,
    interaction.depth = 5,
    shrinkage = 0.1,
    n.minobsinnode = 5,
    bag.fraction = .65,
    train.fraction = 1,
    n.cores = NULL, # will use all cores by default
    verbose = FALSE
  )
}
# ... as well as a function to extract information from the fitted model.
summary_fn <- function(fit) {
  # Generalized Boosted Regression
  summary(fit, plotit = FALSE) %>%
    as_tibble()
}

model_summaries <-
  data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    # We want to fit 5 models, one for each of the following responses:
    c(B, C, E, OC, OLS),
    names_to = "response",
    values_to = "y"
  ) %>%
  nest_by(response) %>%
  mutate(
    fit = list(model_fn(
      # For each response we want to use variables B1 through B11 as predictors.
      y ~ B1 + B2 + B3 + B4 + B5 + B6 + B7 + B8 + B9 + B10 + B11,
      data = data
    ))
  ) %>%
  summarise(
    summary_fn(fit)
  )
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'response'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
model_summaries
#> # A tibble: 55 × 3
#> # Groups:   response [5]
#>    response var    rel.inf
#>    <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1 B        B1    1   e+ 2
#>  2 B        B2    4.11e-29
#>  3 B        B8    1.17e-29
#>  4 B        B3    8.67e-30
#>  5 B        B4    6.88e-30
#>  6 B        B11   5.43e-30
#>  7 B        B5    2.85e-30
#>  8 B        B7    6.14e-31
#>  9 B        B10   3.82e-31
#> 10 B        B6    1.84e-31
#> # … with 45 more rows
```

PS. The gbm models fit your data very poorly. Are you sure that the response is Gaussian? It's easy to check that each response takes two unique values, and that each value is observed exactly 50 times.

```r
data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    # We want to fit 5 models, one for each of the following responses:
    c(B, C, E, OC, OLS),
    names_to = "response",
    values_to = "y"
  ) %>%
  count(
    response, y
  )
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    response     y     n
#>    <chr>    <int> <int>
#>  1 B           20    50
#>  2 B           50    50
#>  3 C           10    50
#>  4 C           20    50
#>  5 E           20    50
#>  6 E           30    50
#>  7 OC          10    50
#>  8 OC          30    50
#>  9 OLS          0    50
#> 10 OLS         10    50
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>